# how to select master slide in OpenOffice ODG document with TinyButStrong TBS

Tags: tinybutstrong, openoffice-impress

I can successfully manipulate fileds on a master slide of a PPTX document with this code:

```
        $TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_SELECT_SLIDE, '1', true); // select master slide
        $TBS->MergeField('abk', 'ainfo', true); // merge field 'abk.ainfo'
```

However, I fail trying to do the same with an ODG file that is just the PPTX file saved in a different format through LibreOffice.

Any clues?

Comment: ODG is the extension for graphics, the extension for presentations is ODP. However, you can save a presentation as ODG, and it will stay a presentation.

Comment: Yes, right, there are minor differences between the two. I need to work on the ODG file for administrative reasons

Answer (score 1):

With OpenTBS last version (1.10.0), the argument for opening the master slide is simply ignored. This is a bug and it will be fixed in the next version.

Waiting for the fix, here is a workaround: in an ODP, the master slide is saved in the `styles.xml` sub-file.
So you can open it with the command:

```
$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_SELECT_FILE, 'styles.xml'); // select master slide
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I am using 1.9.11 and selecting the master slide for PPTX works fine. BTW I figured out the styles.xml thing and it also fixes a related problem as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63038986/